# Property 'select2' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I am using Angular 4 with `select2` plugin. I have already added `@types` for `jquery` and `select2`. Vscode intellisense shows as a method select2 and doesnt throw any error, but angular-cli's compilation fails.

Comment: I would suggest you not to use a library that depends on jQuery, because you can do the same things without it in Angular. If you don't want to manipulate select elements by yourself (it's a very good practice), i suggest you to use a library built in for angular( for example ng-select, [link](https://github.com/basvandenberg/ng-select) ). If you want to go with your current implementation probably you have to declare var $:any after all the import in your component.

Comment: @macvg even after installing ng-select, nothing changed.

Comment: @rajdeep26 are you able to fix this?

Comment: @rajdeep26 please edit your question and copy paste the angular-cli error. Otherwise no answer will be correct.

Comment: @macvag angular cli error is `TS2551: Property 'select2' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'. Did you mean 'select'?`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and fixed it by importing:

```
import 'select2';
```

which I had installed earlier:

```
npm install select2 --save
```

Once you do that, you can use the library through jQuery as usual, and your IDE won't complain about it.

Comment: It was the `import 'select2'` which I missed, you saved my day thank you.

Comment: I tried the above steps and getting this error----Error: src/app/select2.directive.ts:11:35 - error TS2551: Property 'select2' does not exist on type 'JQuery<any>'. Did you mean 'select'? 11 $(this.element.nativeElement).select2();

Comment: I'd need to see your code. The error you describe does not seem to be related to the line of code I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, that's because I imported another library ([sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)), with the wrong jQuery definition.

In `sweetalert2.d.ts` line 885:

```js
/**
 * These interfaces aren't provided by SweetAlert2, but its definitions use them.
 * They will be merged with 'true' definitions.
 */

// tslint:disable:no-empty-interface

interface JQuery {
}
```

This override `JQuery` definition with the wrong result (which originally should be `JQuery<T = HTMLElement>`). After removing it everything runs correctly.